# Why is Ubuntu keep sending TCP SYN packets to port 53 of dns server?

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to get help with my Ubuntu desktop *18.04.01* .

I just installed *Ubuntu 18.04.01* running top of kvm *(fedora server 28)* and having hard time setting up dns access.

While diagnosing why DNS queries from Ubuntu desktop is not responded from my router, I found below packets was sent from Ubuntu.

```
12:29:53.596586 IP 192.168.11.100.45415 > 192.168.11.1.domain: 31141+ AAAA? ntp.ubuntu.com. (32)
12:29:53.597703 IP 192.168.11.100.37220 > 192.168.11.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 574811215, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3560337742 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:29:53.597902 IP 192.168.11.100.37222 > 192.168.11.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 3169117583, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3560337742 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:29:53.598020 IP 192.168.11.100.37224 > 192.168.11.1.domain: Flags [S], seq 4965594, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3560337742 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

What is this SYN request from *Ubuntu desktop* ?

Best Regards,
Yu Watanabe

Comment: Those look like DNS over TCP queries to me. The Ubuntu desktop is trying to establish a TCP session with the DNS server for the purpose of issuing a DNS query to the DNS server.

Comment: And it might try connecting with TCP because UDP DNS is not available.

Comment: I see . This is interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer. Joeqwerty and Tero Kikanen.

So the cause of the TCP packets was that Ubuntu (Guest OS) was unable to communicate with DNS.

However, *root cauase* of this problem was the bridge interface was not sending out dns packets from guest OS to the dns server. I use *kvm* on fedora sever 28 and Ubuntu runs on top of it.

In my case I disabled the netfilter for the bridge interface.

https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Creating_network_initscripts

```
The final step is to disable netfilter on the bridge:

 # cat >> /etc/sysctl.conf <<EOF
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
 EOF
 # sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Now TCP packets are not sent out.